# Sharing youtube video from website via facebook

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, facebook-opengraph

I'm really struggling with sharing youtoube videos from a website via facebook.

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I want to share a video which is hosted on youtube. The video should be playable on facebook. Next to the video I need to have the title and the description. The title links to the website, where people can share the video. Something like this:

[image]

However i always end up with this: 
[image]

I can get the correct "layout" of the share with the image on the left, and the text on the right, but only with an og:image meta tag that points to a non-existent image (404).

As soon as the og:image meta tag points to an existing image, the layout changes. Why does this happen? I'm lost.

Is it the format of the image? (470*236) For my purpose it is crucial that the image AND the text are shared, since the text (actually it is the title) links to the website that should be shared.

Also something really strange, when I'm debugging the "Open Graph Object Debugger" it looks like it is supposed to. The sharer.php delivers the correct "view" on 50% of the ocasion. When it is actually shared, it only works when I have a 404 on the og:image.

This is the content of my "og:video" tag:

```
{
   "url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/7MAVG2BfTHc?autohide=1&version=3",
   "secure_url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/7MAVG2BfTHc?autohide=1&version=3",
   "type": "application\/x-shockwave-flash"
}
```

**EDIT:**
As requested I'm providing more information:
https://graph.facebook.com/834694379943959

```
{
   "id": "834694379943959",
   "application": {
      "id": "969191506424946",
      "name": "fit.immoscout24.ch",
      "url": "http://fit.immoscout24.ch/"
   },
   "created_time": "2015-04-22T12:35:06+0000",
   "description": "D\u00e9niche rapidement ton nouveau logement gr\u00e2ce aux conseils de Michel ! N\u00b01 : strat\u00e9gie ! Utilise des arguments percutants pour convaincre le propri\u00e9taire",
   "image": [
      {
         "height": 360,
         "url": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/B5ZioKe_znM/0.jpg",
         "width": 480
      }
   ],
   "is_scraped": true,
   "title": "Michel Pont",
   "type": "video.other",
   "updated_time": "2015-04-26T20:11:39+0000",
   "url": "http://punch.immoscout24.ch/michel-pont",
   "video": [
      {
         "secure_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B5ZioKe_znM",
         "type": "text/html",
         "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B5ZioKe_znM"
      }
   ]
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I filed a bug report on facebook, when I get an answer I'll update this post.

Comment: Could you include all you og tags that you are using so that we can try to reproduce what you are doing?

Comment: Sure thing: check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpunch.immoscout24.ch%2Fmichel-pont

Comment: If I have this correct you are trying to achieve a certain layout for what you share in the Facebook news feed. If so, this is not possible. Facebook will always alter the way content gets delivered based on how users engage with it. There is no guarantee that you will get the share layout the way you want it.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Except that the actual layout is not the most important thing. What I need is, that i have the video, playable on facebook PLUS the title and the description. basically just like it says under "when shared, this is what will be included". there i get the title and the description, but as soon as I actually share it, only the image and the play button come up. so why is there a difference? that doesn't make sense and is a bug in my opinion.

Comment: @rryter ever get anywhere on this?  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Not really I'm afraid... I gave up. Sorry :)